# Space between two row classes in HTML (Angular)

Tags: html, css

I have 3 rows with 2 columns in each row on my HTML page with some labels and inputs.
I see a lot of space between the rows which I tried removing but didn't work. Is there a way to do it?
 Here's the HTML Code :

```html
<div >
    <h1>
        New Patient Record
    </h1>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column">
<label > <strong>Date</strong> </label>
<input type="date"   name="date" id="date"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="institutes.date">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:0px" >
        <div class="container" style="padding-left: 7.5%" >
            <form #institutesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="instituteLogins(institutesForm)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column">             
                                            
                       
        <h2><strong> Symptoms</strong> </h2>
        <input type="text"  name="symtoms" id="symtoms"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.symtoms">
        
        <br>
        <h2><strong>Diagnosis</strong></h2>
        
        <label> <strong>Condition</strong> </label>
        <input type="text"  name="condition" id="condition"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.condition">
        <label><strong> Advice </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="advice" id="advice"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.advice">
        <br>
        
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2> <strong>Prescription</strong> </h2>
        <br>
        <label><strong> Medication </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="medication" id="medication"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.medication">
        <label><strong> Medicine Type </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="type" id="type"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.type">
        <label><strong>Course</strong></label>
        <input type="text"  id="course" name="course"  class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.course">
        <label><strong> How many per day? </strong></label>
        
        
        <input type="text"  name="cday" id="cday"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.cday">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column">
        <button id="record"  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Add Record</button>
    </div>
</div>
   
       </div>
        <br><br>
        
                    </div>
                     </form>
                    
    </div>
```

Here's what all  I tried: I tried to adjust row spacing using margins, and padding but none of them worked. Is there any other alternative for this?

```css
.modal-dialog.cascading-modal.modal-avatar .modal-header img {
    width: 130px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.modal-dialog.cascading-modal.modal-avatar .modal-header {
    margin: -6rem 2rem -1rem 2rem;
}
.More{
    color: blue;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.column{
    margin : 100px;
}
.row{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

[image: Here's the html page]

Comment: The padding-left: 7.5% is intentional I presume. What space is problematic here? Probably it has something to do with the display property. Could you try to fiddle around with display: flex;?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code **does not demonstrate the issue**. We need the CSS also.

Comment: please share your css page also

Comment: @Remi The 7.5 % was intentional. I have a navigation bar on the left

Comment: I have added the complete css page

Comment: Can you give it a display: block; and float: left;? Perhaps you could also reproduce the error in https://codesandbox.io/s/angular. That way you can isolate the problem, and post the URL here and people can help you debug.

Comment: @Remi Here's the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-l2q6k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Have you saved your edits? There is no HTML and CSS in your codesandbox example.

Comment: Index.html and styles.css are the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing:

```
.column{
  margin: 100px;
}
```

To

```
.column{
  margin-left : 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Will remove the space between the rows. Is that the end result you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the margin-left helped me solve the issue.
Also using 
 to add number of empty spaces vertically solved my UI design issues.

Answer (score -2):

For the space between both rows, you can add the padding-bottom
style="margin-top:-50px"

Comment: The OP is trying to **remove** the extra space, not add to it.

Comment: you can add padding 0 and add the margin-top:-50%;

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a negative margin. This usually causes differences between browsers.